# Staying Up Shavuos Night and Yom Tov Halacha

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, shavuos

There is a Halacha in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim Siman 529:1 that one is supposed to break up his Yom Tov into halves: Half to Hashem and half to himself. The Mishna Berura there elaborates and gives a detailed schedule as to how one should do this. He says that one should wake up and go to shul, daven, learn, Daven Mussaf, go home to eat, come back to shul and Daven Mincha.

Does staying up all night to learn on Shavuos contradict this Halacha? I ask since after Davening the next day, people go to sleep, not learning like the Mishna Berura says one should do.

Comment: A shul I used to attend had the rav insist that people sleep for 2-3 hours after learning all night and come back to Shacharis around 9 AM. Pat if his reasoning was to fulfill what the Mishnah Brurah mentions. Another reason was that he found that neither the chazan nor the congregation had the proper kavanah to daven when they were tired from all night learning. I agree with this rav's thinking. It sounds practical.

Comment: @DanF Going to sleep until 9am violates the Mishnah Berurah anyway. You are supposed to learn _all_ morning. Sleeping extra isn't permitted just because it happened before praying.